# I am trying deploy my flask app on Azure via CloudPanel via uwsgi

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

**Result: Internal Server Error**

NOTE:

1. I am using python version 3.8.16 on this particular app
2. I have removed my actual username & domain in the details provided below
3. Followed the exact steps on: https://www.cloudpanel.io/docs/v2/python/deployment/uwsgi/
4. I am using a subdomain
5. My app runs correctly in development mode on the virtual environment as well as on my local machine
6. uWSGI is listening to the port 8090 as well.

This is my apps main module:

Name: api.py

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import joblib

app = Flask(__name__)
classifier = joblib.load('./model/pipeline.pkl')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    message = "API has been deployed correctly!"
    return render_template('index.html', message=message)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    json_ = request.json

    prediction = classifier.predict(json_['text']).tolist()
    return jsonify({'prediction': prediction[0] })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    classifier = joblib.load('./model/pipeline.pkl')
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is my wsgi file:

```py
from api import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here is my ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins       = python3
master        = true
protocol      = uwsgi
socket        = 127.0.0.1:8090
chdir         = /home/username/htdocs/api.domain.com
wsgi-file     = /home/username/htdocs/api.domain.com/api/wsgi.py
callable      = app

# In case you're using virtualenv uncomment this:
virtualenv = /home/username/htdocs/api.domain.com/env

# Needed for OAuth/OpenID
buffer-size   = 8192

# Reload when consuming too much of memory
reload-on-rss = 250

# Increase number of workers for heavily loaded sites
workers       = 4

# Enable threads for Sentry error submission
enable-threads = true

# Child processes do not need file descriptors
close-on-exec = true

# Avoid default 0000 umask
umask = 0022

#Run as weblate user
uid = username
gid = username

# Enable harakiri mode (kill requests after some time)
# harakiri = 3600
# harakiri-verbose = true

# Enable uWSGI stats server
# stats = :1717
# stats-http = true

# Do not log some errors caused by client disconnects
ignore-sigpipe = true
ignore-write-errors = true
disable-write-exception = true
```

Here is my Vhost file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  {{ssl_certificate_key}}
  {{ssl_certificate}}
  server_name api.domain.com;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  index index.html;

  location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 3600;
    #uwsgi_pass unix:///run/uwsgi/app/weblate/socket;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8090;
  }

  #location ~* ^.+\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|webp|zip|swf)$ {
  #  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
  #  expires max;
  #  access_log on;
  #}

  if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
  }
}
```

After restarting nginx & uwsgi as well as rebooting my instance it should display this when I open the site:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k6ae.png)

Comment: Check uWSGI logs in `/var/log/uwsgi/app/api.domain.com.uwsgi.log`. This could be a Python error or an error in `wsgi.py` file.

Comment: Or the uid / gid combo doesn't have access to the python file or the virtual environment. Or the pythonpath is set wrongly. The log file should give more information indeed.